# Host a WCF service for my Azure Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

I have two projects in my solution:

**1. WCF Service Library**

**2. MVC project** Azure free website which uses the WCF service.

Everything works as it should when not deployed, (localhost), but I have no idea how to use my WCF service from my MVC project when I have **deployed** my MVC project to Azure.

**Solution:**

### [image: My solution]

**WCF Service Library project app config:**

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/UserWCF" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IUserService" contract="Fildela_WCF.IFildelaService"
        name="WSHttpBinding_IUserService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="REFT\filip" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="Fildela_WCF.FildelaService">
        <endpoint address="UserWCF" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Fildela_WCF.IFildelaService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

**MVC project web config:**

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/UserWCF" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IFildelaService" contract="FildelaServiceReference.IFildelaService"
        name="WSHttpBinding_IFildelaService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="DEFAULT\Filip" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
```

**How I use my service on localhost:**

1. Right click Service References folder in my MVC project and click "Add Service Reference".
2. Click discover and select the localhost service that pops up under Services.
3. I can now access my functions that resides in my WCF project: ServiceClient1 test = new ServiceClient1();
   Test.HelloWorld();

I have tried to replace the localhost address with my azure website but it doesn't work, (mywebsite.azurewebsites.net).

I am all new with this so bear with me. I have two projects in my solution now and when I publish my MVC project, the WCF project wont come with the publish, right?
So how am I supposed to use the WCF project from my MVC project when the web project is published to Azure?

Am I supposed to use an Azure Service Bus?

Should I go with cloudapp instead?

How? What? Why?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to convert my Azure website project to an cloudapp project. Publishing two seperat Azure websites just because of the WCF service is not very efficient.